# If statement with cookiecutter has bad syntax

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I'm trying to use `cookiecutter` as the first time in my django project in order to create project skeleton.

In my `cookiecutter.project_slug`, I have a **base.py** settings file with this part at the end:

```
import cookiecutter

{% if cookiecutter.use_celery == 'y' %}
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
# Add a one-minute timeout to all Celery tasks.
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60
{% endif %}
```

But it appears that Django doesn't like the syntax from this part: `invalid syntax error`

Do you know How I can write a good syntax for this part above ?

Thank you !

Comment: I guess you might be forgetting the '-' at the end of the if tag
{% if  -%}
{%- endif %}

Comment: @HigorRossato It doesn't work by adding `-` ;)

Comment: What command are you running that gives `invalid syntax error`? The `{% if %}` tags are in a jinja template that cookiecutter renders to generated the actual `base.py` file. You shouldn't ever be running the template it Python, and I don't think the template requires `import cookiecutter`.

Comment: @Alasdair I'm trying to generate html doc files through sphinx_doc and the issue given by `make html` is : `There is a syntax error in your configuration file: invalid syntax (base.py, line 238)
Did you change the syntax from 2.x to 3.x?
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'html' failed`. The issue is pointing to this celery part and my Pycharm gives me an error too according to bad syntax.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to document the project skeleton in sphinx, or the actual project you create from it? It might help if you gave a step-by-step explanation of what you did to get to this point. Does `base.py` contain other `{% if cookiecutter.... %}` blocks? If `base.py` is a template, then it's not meant to be a valid Python file, so you would expect errors from PyCharm.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you cloned [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) and tried to run some Django specific commands like `pip install -r requirements/local.txt` or `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`? This does not work, let me explain why.

Cookiecutter-django is based on [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) which is a command-line utility that creates project templates. Or in other words you can **generate a Django starter project with help of cookiecutter-django**.

Instead of cloning cookiecutter-django, run following commands as described [here](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/README.rst#usage).

```
$ pip install "cookiecutter>=1.4.0"
$ cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django
```

Now you will be asked some questions from cookiecutter-django. For example if you want use celery or not. See also [options page](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project-generation-options.html#). According the options you choose cookiecutter-django will setup the project for you.

After going through all steps you can run Django specific commands – see [here](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally.html#) or [here if you did choose Docker](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally-docker.html).